# Set JRE to use Windows trust store, specifically the user's trust store

Tags: java, windows, ssl, certificate, truststore

Summary: Java option `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=WINDOWS-ROOT` allows Java to use the Windows trust store for the *computer account.* What option allows it to use the Windows trust store for the *user account*?

We have a Java application that we run on our Windows clients. The application gets data from various sources, some of which use certificates that are not in the default `cacerts` file.

When a user selects an item that accesses the external data, they are prompted to download the external site's certificate. Due to our security settings, the `cacerts` file is read-only for users. Because JRE can't import the cert into `cacerts`, the external isn't downloaded. And the user is prompted over and over to download the cert.

When a user is given write access to `cacerts`, the issue doesn't occur. But our security team will not let us grant write access to that file to regular users. Their policy is that no files on the `C:` drive, outside the user's own profile, should be read-write.

We thought we found a workaround to make Java use the Windows trust store. We added the flag `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=WINDOWS-ROOT` to the startup script. This forced Java to use the Windows trust store, which users can write to.

Unfortunately, users can only write to their certificate store, not to the computer's certificate store. When we run the app as an administrator, the certificate is imported into the computer's store. After that, regular users are not prompted to download the cert. However, if we don't run it once with admin rights, the cert is not imported, because Java tries to write to the Windows *computer account* store, which is locked down just as tightly as `cacerts`.

Is there a flag to force Java to use the entire Windows trust store, not just the computer account's store?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A keystore of type **Windows-ROOT should work** -- it should access the TrustedRootCAs portion (line in MMC/certmgr.msc, tab in inetopt.cpl) of the store for the current user. On my system, which is 8.1 Home with UAC at max, but not in a domain or workgroup and no policy changes (at least none I authorized), Java code is able to insert into Windows-ROOT -- BUT it does pop a dialog about "Warning: about to install CA cert blah blah this may be a security risk blah blah" which I have to click; if the process doesn't have access to the 'workstation' (display) I don't know what happens and it wouldn't surprise me if it fails. Confirmed with both my normal id (local,admin) and Guest (local,peon); as a standalone system I have no real computer account, only 'local machine' which IINM is actually LocalSystem, and the insert does NOT go there.

You could try instead **Windows-MY** which should and for me does access the Personal portion of the store for (again) the current user; for me that works WITHOUT the dialog described above. Personal is *intended* for certs with privatekeys that can be used to authenticate *this* machine/user to server(s) or recipient(s), and having in there a cert-only used to trust another system may confuse or even alarm your more knowledgeable users, but it does work for me.

Comment: Just in case anyone comes here looking for a solution for Gradle (as I did), create a file named `gradle.properties` on the project root containing the line `systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT`.

Comment: It was working with Oracle JDK8, but doesn't seems to work with OpenJDK 11 :(

Comment: There is code to do this in OpenJdk 11 source: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/jdk.crypto.mscapi/windows/classes/sun/security/mscapi/SunMSCAPI.java#L88

Answer (score 6):

Besides `javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT` I had to also define `javax.net.ssl.trustStore=NUL` for this to work on Windows, even though `println(System.getProperty('javax.net.ssl.trustStore'))` printed `null`. See also https://newbedev.com/import-windows-certificates-to-java

Since I needed this for Gradle I had to add the following to my `gradle.properties`:

```
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=NUL
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT
```

After running Gradle once with this configuration I no longer needed the `systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=NUL`, until I added another maven repository. Then I got a `PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target` again.

It seems that Gradle caches this certificate somewhere, because after deleting the `.gradle` directory in my user home, I also needed `systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=NUL` again. So it is probably best to leave it there.

Comment: Gradle does not cache certificates but dependencies. So if a dependency is already there, it does not have to connect to the repo and does not have to trust the cert. You can force the connect with `--refresh-dependencies`.

Comment: I guess the deamon reads certificates on its start. `gradlew --stop` should help in this case

Comment: This is the complete answer. The chosen one is not. Saved me a chore of importing certificate to the java trust-store (possibly multiple times).

Answer (score 1):

The [JSSE Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#InstallationAndCustomization) answers your question.

> In this case, if such a property exists but the file it specifies does
>   not, then no truststore is used. If no javax.net.ssl.trustStore
>   property exists, then a default truststore is searched for. If a
>   truststore named java-home/lib/security/jssecacerts is found, it is
>   used. If not, then a truststore named java-home/lib/security/cacerts
>   is searched for and used (if it exists).

If you don't have permissions to overwrite one of these two files jssecacerts or cacerts, the answer to your question is NO.