# Is the path of JDK changed from jre to jbr in new Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am behind proxy and facing PKIX path building error .

Solution is to add the problematic cert to lib/security certs file and then from the Android Studio add certificate

But with new Android Studio JDK path has been changed to jbr : C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr

previously it used to be C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre

Comment: Instead of manipulating the Java trust store you could try to change the Java command-line and let it trust the Windows root CAs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49176390/150978

Answer (score 2):

I prefer don't change the Android Studio certificates (cacerts file located in *Android Studio\jre\lib\security*) because it can cause problems with Android Studio updates. We have resolved this problem adding these lines to the system gradle.properties file.

*C:\Users<MY_USER>.gradle\gradle.properties*

```
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=C\:\\Windows\\win.ini
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT
```

Comment: Is there a mac OS equivalent for this step?